# How to get user's secondary email addresses using Facebook APIs

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I know how to get an user's email address using PHP SDK & Facebook Graph API or FQL.

However, I still couldn't find how to get user's network email addresses, or secondary email addresses.

For example the user belongs to "College" network, I want to get his "user@college.edu" email. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the Facebook Dev references and can't find it.

Getting the primary e-mail address from a user is part of the extended permissions because it's highly private data.

There is no extended permission for non-primary e-mail addresses which means it's not possible, otherwise it would be in the extented permissions list at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions.